# Why does the $scope member being accessed thrice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my code:

```js
"use strict";

var App = angular.module('SampleApp', []);

App.controller('EmpCtrl', ['$scope', 'EmpCalcSvc', function ($scope, EmpCalcSvc) {
    $scope.Empno = 1001;
    $scope.Ename = "Test";
    $scope.Sal = 4500;
    $scope.Deptno = 20;
    $scope.GetAnnSal = function () {
        return EmpCalcSvc.GetAnnSal($scope.Sal);
    };
}]);

App.service('EmpCalcSvc', function() {
    this.GetAnnSal = function (salary) {
        console.log(salary);
        return salary * 12;
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="SampleApp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px">Employee Id:</td>
                <td>{{Empno}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>{{Ename}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Salary:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="Sal"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Department:</td>
                <td>{{Deptno}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Annual Salary:</td>
                <td>{{GetAnnSal()}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I modify the value in the textbox, $scope.GetAnnSal gets executed thrice!

What am I missing here to get it executed only once?
Or, am I fundamentally wrong in understanding the concept here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you typing or pasting the new value into the textbox?

Comment: Pressing a single digit (just one keyboard key, inside the textbox) is good enough to fire the method thrice.

Comment: It seems to be working for me.. Every number I type into the text box is multiplied by 12 in the 'Annual Salary' field. Isn't this what you want to happen?

Comment: Of course, it is what it is supposed to do.  My only concern is that it executes the method "thrice", unnecessarily, for every key I press.  The result is accurate in all cases of execution.  But, why would it execute 3 times for every (digit) Key I press on the keyboard, is the question.

Comment: I am not super familiar with this, but it could be listening for multiple key events. so keyup, keydown, keypress. Thus triggering the function multiple times.

Comment: angular does a LOT of extra work. you use frameworks for ease of coding, not for CPU efficiency...

Comment: @jonode, I have not thought about those events.  May be you are right.  Thanks.

Comment: @dandavis, it is just not the CPU efficiency I worried about.  Imagine that I have an angular service which accesses a web service (say for a "typeahead" textbox).  I will end-up with three roundtrips for every key I press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is at `<td>{{GetAnnSal()}}</td>` line. Angular will execute this function in each digest cycle. It is better to put a scope variable inside interpolation instead of a function.

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n75zWXJmIriiMfSEHOqq?p=preview). Where I have put the function call GetAnnSal() in ng-change and set the evaluated value in interpolation directive.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is a "digest cycle" or a couple of web links explaining the same?

Comment: You can check section titled "Integration with the browser event loop" at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope link. This should explain you about what happens when you enter anything in textbox and how the model update happens in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Have a simple ng-change and you are done. No need to call the function in a td as it will be $watched.

```js
"use strict";

var App = angular.module('SampleApp', []);

App.controller('EmpCtrl', ['$scope', 'EmpCalcSvc', function ($scope, EmpCalcSvc) {
    $scope.Empno = 1001;
    $scope.Ename = "Test";
    $scope.Sal = 4500;
    $scope.Deptno = 20;
    $scope.GetAnnSal = function () {
        $scope.computedSalary = EmpCalcSvc.GetAnnSal($scope.Sal);
        //return EmpCalcSvc.GetAnnSal($scope.Sal);
    };
}]);

App.service('EmpCalcSvc', function() {
    this.GetAnnSal = function (salary) {
        console.log(salary);
        return salary * 12;
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="SampleApp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px">Employee Id:</td>
                <td>{{Empno}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>{{Ename}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Salary:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="Sal" ng-change="GetAnnSal(Sal)"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Department:</td>
                <td>{{Deptno}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Annual Salary:</td>
                <td>{{computedSalary}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  You are just 3 min late! to the very similar answer above.  Where can I find more information about $watch (especially in detail)?

Comment: angular documentation is full of it. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: do go over ngBindOnce very nice module to reduce watchers